# Using a jar as ressource with maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have the same problem as in question [Reference jars inside a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357136/reference-jars-inside-a-jar). I have a jar containing icons for my application. That jar resides in `src/main/ressources`. On build maven places this jar as is into the applications jar (so I have a jar inside a jar). Therefore I cannot reference the files in the icons.jar anymore.

What is the recommended approach or best practice to handle this situation?

Comment: either make it a separate artefact and add it as a dependency or unpack it at compile time add put the individual files into the classpath.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I was hoping for some more _elegant_ solution. But I will go along with your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use this jar on the classpath (as a dependency), you should be able to reference your icons from there. This is more or less what's done in webjars (see http://www.webjars.org/) with JS/Css/images