# External jar files not working when jar file created

Tags: java, linux, classpath

I am writing a program in java to convert xlsx to csv file. I have 4 to 5 jar files which I set permanently in classpath using this-

```
vim ~/.bashrc
export CLASSPATH="/path/to/file1":"/path/to/file2":"${CLASSPATH}"
```

when I created the jar file of my program then again it stopped working and  I was getting error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook
```

Again it seems issue related to classpath. Now how to solve this ?
Below are the jar files which I exported in classpath-

```
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar
jxl.jar
poi-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
poi-excelant-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
poi-ooxml-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
poi-scratchpad-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
xbean-2.3.0.jar
```

Comment: You're more than likely still missing some jar files.  Apache POI has other dependencies it needs to run.  List your jar files here and someone can help.

Comment: Are you sure that the class that is not found is in one of your specified JAR files?

Comment: Yeah I listed all the jar files in my questions. If it's not there then how my program is working if I run directly (without creating jar file)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357136/reference-jars-inside-a-jar

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable 'CLASSPATH' is independent of java runtime.

For indicate java classpath for your jar file, you are send as parameter. For example:

```
java -cp  -.;/path/to/file1:/path/to/file2 -jar YourApp.jar
```

Or, you can create a batch file and run with .bat file (win) or .sh file (linux).
For example:

```
java -cp .;bin/* com.example.MainClass
```

Copy all jar files in bin directory included your application, and com.example.MainClass represent the complete name of your main class.

You will run your app with the batch file.