# Import libraries imported by library?

Tags: java, libraries

I have application **A** and my own library **B**. My own library **B** imports other library **C**. In application **A** I use method from my own library **B**. This method uses classes from library **C**, and crashes, because **in application A I can't import classes from library C**. I know that I can add library **C** twice - to my app and to library **B** and then it should work, but I want use it only once. Is it possible or should I start crying ?

---

Summing, I think that this scheme should help to understand my question: 
 **A** (pplication) --> **B** (myOwnLibrary) --> **C** (otherlibrary)

**A** imports classes from **B** 
 **B** imports classes from **C** 
 **A** use method from **B**, which use classes from **C**, and crashes because in **A** I can't import classes from **C** 
What should I do if I want import **C** only once and have my app working?

---

Comment: Are other libraries classes in the classpath ?

Comment: Why can't application A import classes from C?

Comment: @PhilippeGeek You should post that as the answer. I'll upvote.

Comment: @mttdbrd A question as an answer?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo Well, reformat as a statement. This is clearly a classpath issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference jars inside a jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357136/reference-jars-inside-a-jar)

Comment: @PhilippeGeek No, they aren't

Comment: @PhilippeGeek Already upvoted.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Only if he works with jars

Comment: FWIW a dependency management and build tool like maven can make life a lot easier.

Comment: @user2645214 So please consider my answer below

Comment: @PhilippeGeek if they are not jars and works with libraries in Java, I don't know which library he can import (assuming no DLL usage :) ).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, i just thinked the worst

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza My library C contains dll's ;)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include compiled classes from your "otherlibrary" in your classpath.