# Execute a jar inside another jar in java

Tags: java, maven

I have an executable jar(mainjar) with me, i have created it using a maven project. When i pass some argument to his jar, it will execute another jar(execjar) file which is placed inside the src/main/resource of mainjar. The problem is i am not able to access the execjar inside the mainjar. Here is my folder structure of mainjar

> ```
> src/main/java
>     MainClass
>         code to execute execjar- 'java -jar execjar'
> src/main/resource/
>     execjar
> ```

The problem is when i package the mainjar using maven assembly plugin, i am not able to access the execjar inside the mainjar- nothing happens when i execute the mainjar.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: If you want to call java code from java code, you don't need to call `java`

Comment: ??? Why don't you instantiate the Main class of the execjar Manifest and execute it that way?

Comment: yes, i understand , but the requirement is to create a utility(mainjar) hiding the details of the jar (execjar) which is being executed inside it

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar execjar")?

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357136/reference-jars-inside-a-jar), apparently it's not possible.

Comment: i added the execjar to the build path, i am able to access its mainclass in the mainjar. But i am not able to package the mainjar , it says the class not found

Answer (score 0):

Look at the shade plugin to create an uberjar instead.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

Comment: is it enough to add the <configuration><transformers><transformer
         implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.IncludeResourceTransformer">
         <resource>src/main/resources/execjar</resource>
         <file>execjar.jar</file>
        </transformer></transformers></configuration>

Comment: try it out. You are in a better position to test whether it works as intended.. However, I doubt you comprehend.