# Issues while creating a library

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, libraries

I have a wrapper that I've built ontop of the Netty library.

I'm trying to export the wrapper as a .JAR so when I add it to another project I can use it's features.

The .JAR file has the Netty.jar file in the dependencies folder, however when I try to import something in my project that has my .jar file as a library, I can't import any netty functions.

Of-course, the .JAR file can access the Netty.Jar fine.

Is there any way to make it so I don't have to have my .jar and the netty.jar as libraries, and instead just have my .jar file share the netty.jar to the project?

---

Example:

```
-|_My Project
---|_MyLibrary.Jar
-----| Netty.Jar
```

---

Which would mean you would only have to import 'MyLibrary.Jar' to use the features that come with 'Netty.Jar'

Or do I have to do it like this

---

```
-|_My Project
---| MyLibrary.Jar
---| Netty.Jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard Java is not able to load Jar-Files within Jar-Files. So you have to do it the second way you propose, to have the two libraries next to each other.
What you can do is to have a Manifest in `MyLibrary.jar` that contains a classpath which points to the `Netty.jar`. This way, you will only have to add `MyLibrary.jar` to the classpath, but not both. But still, both jar files need to be on the filesystem, just not on the classpath.

Comment: So the user ( if someone else wanted to use this ) would still have to download the Netty.jar, even though it's already inside of 'MyLibrary.Jar' ?

Comment: Yes, at least with standard Java. There are alternative class loaders, e.g. OneJar, that might help, but I wouldn't use them for a library, only for standalone applications. Also have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357136/reference-jars-inside-a-jar

Comment: What a drag, I guess the other alternative is to use the source of the Netty library in my project, instead of just referencing the .Jar as a library, and then building all of it into a .Jar, would this give me the result I'm looking for?