# Java classpath command line with opencsv writer

Tags: java, classpath, opencsv

How to include all jar files in Java? I'm using command prompt.

My jar files is stored on C:\test\java

jarfiles is:

```
commons-io.jar, commons-lang.jar, opencsv.jar
```

And my java program is also stored on C:\test\java

I've searched on google but it seems I cannot find the proper way of using classpath.

I'm currently on C:\test\java and using this command

> javac -cp ".;commons-io.jar;commons-lang.jar;opencsv.jar;" JavaTest.java

And it's compiling successfully but when I run my java program with this line

> Java JavaTest

I'm having a error with the opencsvWriter.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoclassDefFoundError: au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVWriter
```

I cannot determine if classpath is wrong or on the writer is wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when you try adding the same -cp as in your Javac command to your Java command?

Comment: WTH! It works! You're awesome!

Comment: ;) cool. I'll make it into an answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `javac` command will not link togther libraries into a single executable file unlike how the c/c++ linker can with object files. Instead, you have to specify the same classes in your classpath when you go to run the compiled java file:

```
java -cp ".;commons-io.jar;commons-lang.jar;opencsv.jar;" JavaTest
```

You could optionally bundle all of the files into a single jar, and then specify your classpath inside the manifest file located in the newly created jar.

Some additional reading on that here:

[Reference jars inside a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357136/reference-jars-inside-a-jar)