# How to package dependencies into output jar?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, jar

I am trying to make my application work in a stand alone jar. The problem is, a jar is generated for my program, and a bunch of other jars are generated for the libraries. Is there any way to get these jars to get inside one? I am using Gradle if that helps.

The IntelliJ IDEA artifact config:

[image]

The output directory:

[image]

What I expected (and want) to happen:

[image]

Comment: Added a picture for what I would like to be the result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871656/using-gradle-to-build-a-jar-with-dependencies refers to this as an uberjar or a fatjar. Using maven this is called a shaded jar.

Comment: Instead of merging all the jars into a fat jar, just put them all in the same folder and enhance the manifest to specify the classpath, so they're all loaded when you run with `java -jar`.

Comment: @Andreas I want to release my software as a stand along file. That way it simplifies the download process. It does work with having all the jars spread out, but that isn't what I want to do.

Comment: It appears that this cannot be done normally: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357136/reference-jars-inside-a-jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a fat-jar (jar file with all it's dependencies inside). It's not a big problem for Gradle, you just need to make one additional task of type jar, which will collect all the dependencies and zip it alltogether

There are many examples, how you can do it, [here is one of them](http://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/). Take a closer look at task fatJar:

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {        
  baseName = project.name + '-all'
  from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
  with jar
}
```

Comment: I have never used Gradle before for building, it just does whatever IntelliJ IDEA does by default.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's a default Idea's behaviour, because it's not standart Gradle's behaviour. And the only Idea does - is call the gradle script. And furthermore, it will put all the dependencies inside a single jar, but they'll be unziped

Comment: You can configure the way stuff is built inside IDEA, I don't see anything about the specific build stuff that I have configured inside build.gradle

Comment: Ok, now I see, you don't use your gradle scripts to pack the artfacts, good. But anyway, not sure that it's possible to do like you want it, because you need a specific classloader for this, take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar

Comment: So, if you need just a single jar, why don't you try to do it with unziped classes added to the root of your jar? I'm pretty sure, it's possible to do not only with maven or gradle, but with Idea too.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up just using the example you gave above, took some figuring out how to do it though.