# Intellij Executable Jar with embedded jar files

Tags: intellij-idea, executable-jar

I am able to get Intellij to make an executable .jar file that has all the classes extracted from my 3rd party .jar files. I am wondering if there is a way to get Intellij to embed the 3rd party .jar files and not extract the classes. I can do this with eclipse but have yet to find the magic sauce within intellij. Any hints ??

Comment: No, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891.

Comment: Can you point to Eclipse feature that supports jars inside jars? Does it use some custom classloader for that?

Comment: See the following link for how eclipse enables such packaging: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357136/reference-jars-inside-a-jar

Comment: Thanks for the information. You can use the same One-JAR via Ant or Maven in IntelliJ IDEA, it doesn't seem to be Eclipse specific feature. As I thought, it's using the custom classloader.

Comment: The company I am working for uses Gradle....I haven't figured out how to do it with gradle yet. Any ideas ?

Comment: See https://github.com/rholder/gradle-one-jar.