# How to reference a external Jar that has to stay at determined place

Tags: java, eclipse, sdk, installation, runnable

I try to build an runnable jar file. I know how to include the necessary jar libraries into my generated jar. But i am using an SDK and am referencing to one jar of it, which has to stay at this necessary place. So if I copy the jar into some other folder (like lib folder in my project) it doesn´t work. Does anyone know how i can reference this jar file?

Comment: add it to your classpath?

Comment: ..or use maven?

Comment: No, its already in my classpath, I can run the application within eclipse, but not as a exported runnableJar file

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12357552/2310289

Comment: @ScaryWombat thanks for your answer, but i dont have a jar into a jar. My problem is the i need to reference a external jar file, which has to stay at a specially place because its referencing other files. So in eclipse, i cant just add it to my classpath and the jar stays at its place. but if i export my application into a runnable jar, eclipse packages or exports a referenced jar files into the new runnarble jar.

Comment: read the answer again. *By using the Class-Path header in the manifest,*

Comment: However you do it, you must allow the JVM that runs the jar to find the required library. There are two simple ways. 1) When launching the jar, provide the `-cp` option with the required jar.  2) Add a manifest that includes a `Class-Path` header.  Option 2 is less portable as it hardcodes the external jar file location, while option 1 means you can change it at runtime if needed.

Comment: Sorry, still don´t know how to do that...

Comment: The solution was to copy the .jar and some other files the .jar referenced into the same folder because there were realtive paths linked in the .jar