# How to add classpath to Gradle JavaExec task to execute a runnable jar?

Tags: java, spring, gradle

My application requires `spring-context` library. So in my `build.gradle` file, I add this dependency,

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:5.1.6.RELEASE'
}
```

I also want to create a runnable jar file, the `jar` task looks like,

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'my.package.my.main.class'
    }
}
```

Everything is ok when I launched the build file,

```
gradle build
```

But when I tried to execute this runnable jar application,

```
task runJar(dependsOn: jar, type: JavaExec) {
    classpath(configurations.compile)
    main = '-jar'; args 'build/libs/my-runnable.jar'
}
```

Console thrown `NoClassDefFoundError`,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext
...
...
```

I've tried `sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath`, problem remain the same,

```
task runJar(dependsOn: jar, type: JavaExec) {
    classpath(sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath)
    main = '-jar'; args 'build/libs/my-runnable.jar'
}
```

I checked the `classpath` files collection,

```
classpath.each {
    println it.name
}
```

`spring-context` package was right there,

```
spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-jcl-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar
```

Then I tried another walk-around approach to solve this. I extracted all class files from those `.jar` libraries, and included them directly in my final `runnable.jar`,

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'my.package.my.main.class'
    }

    configurations.compile.each {
        from(project.zipTree(it))
    }
}
```

And this solution works. But such a "fat jar" is not what I want.

I am a newcomer of gradle. This really confused me. Any one can help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After about 3 hours work, a simple truth is:

> **When you specify -jar then the -cp parameter will be ignored.**

Some detailed discussion is in this question:

> [Run a JAR file from the command line and specify classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413014/run-a-jar-file-from-the-command-line-and-specify-classpath)

There are 2 simple walk-around solutions:

1. Extract all `.class` files directly into your executable jar as I mentioned in my question.

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'my.package.my.main.class'
    }

    configurations.compile.each {
        from(project.zipTree(it))
    }
}
```

2. Second solution is to add a `Class-Path` parameters in `manifest` file.

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'your.main.class.full.name'
        attributes 'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.name }.join(' ')
    }
}
```

Make sure you can find `.jar` libraries in your local system. Ex, simply copy them into a same directory,

```
task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'build/libs/'
}
```

After that my `build/libs/` directory looks like,

```
build
├── libs
│   ├── my-runnable-app.jar
│   ├── spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar
│   ├── spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar
│   ├── spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar
│   ├── spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar
│   ├── spring-expression-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar
│   └── spring-jcl-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar
```

Notice that all `.jar` libraries locate out side `my-runnable-app.jar`. If you want to include them in you `my-runnable-app.jar`, you need `One-Jar` toolkit. For more information about `One-Jar`, please read this question:

> [Reference jars inside a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357136/reference-jars-inside-a-jar)