# Where are the custom class loader generated by Eclipse when using a jar inside a jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, eclipse-plugin

With Eclpise (and other tools), it is possible to include a dependency jar inside another jar (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31269646/11824428)). When Eclipse do that, it generates a custom class loader, because "classic" class loaders are not able to find a class in a jar that is inside another jar.

To create my jar (`package.final.jar`), I :
- Imported the jar to include (`dep.jar`) inside a `libs/` folder in my project ;
- Added `dep.jar` in MANIFEST.MF -> Runtime -> Classpath (so it added the line `Bundle-ClassPath: libs/dep.jar,.` to my manifest) ;
- Exported my project as a *deployable plug-ins and fragments*.

And `package.final.jar` contains only this structure :

```
-META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
-package/-class1.class
         -class2.class
         .
         .
         .
-libs/dep.jar
```

So I am wondering, where is the custom class loader created by Eclipse ?

Comment: 'deployable plug-ins and fragments' is for Eclipse plugin-ins (or fragments). These are very different from ordinary jars. The Eclipse / OSGi plug-in classloaders deal with these.

Comment: @greg-449 Okay, but what is different exactly ? I can see that the manifest is different, but is there any other difference in the jar ?

Comment: The difference in the MANIFEST.MF is key. The `Bundle-Classpath` tells the Eclipse / OSGi plug-in system how to deal with the included jars - nothing else understands this entry in the manifest. It only works when installed as an Eclipse plug-in (or another OSGi container).

Comment: @greg-449, Okay, it is simple as that ! So if I create a jar manually (with command-line), and put a MANIFEST.MF with `Bundle-Classpath`, the plug-in system will also know how to deal with the included jar ?

Comment: You can build it however you like as long as the MANIFEST.MF is correct. Most Eclipse plug-ins are built using [tag:maven] + [tag:tycho] these days. In future if you are asking about Eclipse plug-ins please say so and use the [tag:eclipse-plugin] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Eclipse plug-ins the `Bundle-ClassPath` entry in the plug-in's MANIFEST.MF tells the Eclipse / OSGi system which classes and jars in the main plug-in jar are part of the class path.

There is no extra code added to the plug-in jar, the Eclipse class loaders deal with the included jars.

So you can build the jar however you like as long as the MANIFEST.MF is correct. Using maven + Eclipse tycho is common these days.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the following folder inside your jar:
org/eclipse/jdt/internal/jarinjarloader

Containing the Classloader etc.:

- JIJConstants.class
- JarRsrcLoader$ManifestInfo.class
- JarRsrcLoader.class
- RsrcURLConnection.class
- RsrcURLStreamHandler.class
- RsrcURLStreamHandlerFactory.class

You can also check it if you look into the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF-File to see what Main-Class is set

Comment: I don't have this folder. Maybe my question was not specific enough. I updated it.

Comment: My solution only "works" if you export it as "Runnable Jar File". When there is no specific item in your main-class-Manifest-Entry I would suggest that the platform you're running your jar-files on has the ClassLoader included.