# (JAR file): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jar

I've little experience with Java and JAR files. I've downloaded a JAR file provided to me which seems to contain all of the necessary dependencies, but when I try to run `java -jar MyJar.jar`, it throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/HttpClient
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:435)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 3 more
```

The JAR file itself seems to contain all of the necessary dependencies as outlined in the `MANIFEST.MF` file:

[image: JAR contents]

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ amqp-client-5.6.0.jar jackson-core-2.9.8.jar jacks
 on-databind-2.9.8.jar jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar jackson-dataforma
 t-yaml-2.9.8.jar snakeyaml-1.23.jar slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar slf4j-log4j12
 -1.7.5.jar log4j-1.2.17.jar httpclient-4.5.8.jar httpcore-4.4.11.jar 
 commons-logging-1.2.jar commons-codec-1.11.jar
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: TRECISExternalClient
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

I was wondering if there's something I'm missing or if it possible that something is malformed. Happy to provide more information if needed.

Comment: I guess HttpClient is not found in the classpath because it is contained in another jar file. There is a question answering that at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357136/reference-jars-inside-a-jar. Here is the official JAR documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Comment: @carlosvin This works with the Eclipse Class Loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue wasn't with the JAR file itself but rather that I had multiple versions of OpenJDK on my system. Purging other versions and reinstalling OpenJDK v1.8.0 (openjdk-8-jdk on Ubuntu repos) solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can check below the link for complete implementation of the class `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader`

https://github.com/U-Alberta/exemplar/blob/master/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/jarinjarloader/JarRsrcLoader.java

Refer to line no 47 `if (rsrcPath.endsWith("/"))`, I think you have to separate each jar with `./`. Besides I see there is a blank space in this line after slash `/` in `Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ amqp-client-5.6.0.jar`. It should be `Rsrc-Class-Path: ./amqp-client-5.6.0.jar`. `HttpClient` is already available as per the image.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue as I've seen similar manifest files using JarRsrcLoader which list them the way I have in my manifest file.